# Why can't I call an external function into a promise code?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension, javascript-objects

I've created a Google Chrome Extension that checks for DOM changes on a website (creation of divs, deletion of divs or updation of class names of divs).
The code I'm using for that is:

```
function changestatus(){//code here}

function handleDivChanges() {
    const sites = [
        "https://www.site1.com/play/*",
        "https://www.site1.com/game/*",
    ];

    var status = getCookie('status');

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
            var currentWebsite = tabs[0].url;
            const isMatch = sites.some(pattern => {
            const regex = new RegExp("^" + pattern.replace(/\*/g, ".*") + "$");
            const tab = tabs[0];
            if (regex.test(currentWebsite) && (status == 'on')) {
                chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                target: { tabId: tab.id },
                function: getHTMLData
                }, (injectionResults) => {
                if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                    reject(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
                } else {
                    resolve(injectionResults[0].result);
                }
                });
            }
        });
    
        function getHTMLData() {
            function isPieceClassName(class_name) {
                var tokens = class_name.split(" ");
                if (tokens.length != 3) {
                    return false;
                }
                var piece_type = tokens.find(function (token) {return token.length == 2});
                var piece_position = tokens.find(function (token) {return token.startsWith("square")});
                return piece_type != undefined && piece_position != undefined;
            }
            
            var observer_config = {
                attributes: true,
                subtree: true,
                attributeOldValue: true,
                attributeFilter: ['class']
            };
            var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) { 
                if (mutations.some(function(mutation) {
                    return (
                        (mutation.oldValue == "board" || mutation.oldValue == "board-flipped") 
                        && mutation.target.className != mutation.oldValue
                    )
                })) {
                }
        
                var move_mutation = mutations.filter(function(mutation) {
                    return (
                        isPieceClassName(mutation.oldValue) &&
                        isPieceClassName(mutation.target.className)
                    )
                });
                if (move_mutation.length > 0) {
                    console.log("Move detected!");
                    changestatus();
                }
            });
            var board = document.documentElement;
            observer.observe(board, observer_config);
        }
    });
    });
}

handleDivChanges();
```

The 'Move Detected' statement is logged however the `changestatus()` function doesn't run saying it cannot find any such function.
I understand that the getHTMLData() function runs on a different scope and hence cannot read the changestatus() function, and so I'm looking for solution to be able to run the function inside off getHTMLData().

Thanks for your time!

PS: I cannot add changestatus() function inside off getHTMLData() as the changestatus() for one uses promises and secondly the changestatus() uses other functions which in turn use more functions that requires promises. I inturn require another solution to call the changestatus() function.